# Do you need to get copyright separately from a creative commons license?

Tags: copyright, creative-commons

I understand the types of creative commons licensing, but does a creative commons license replace copyright altogether?  If I file for a creative commons license for something that I want to make distributable but not alterable, do I need to copyright it in addition to the creative commons license, or does the license take care of all IP needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No, CC does not replace copyright.

A creative commons license is one way to **use** the copyright that you already have the moment you make an original creative work. Without a copyright, a creative commons license does nothing. You don't need to do anything to get a copyright.

However if you plan to exploit a work commercially, or want to be sure that it is well protected, you can gain additional protection in the US and some other countries by **registering** the copyright. US registration can be done online at [this page](https://www.copyright.gov/registration/). The benefits of US registration are described on [this page](https://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/faq-general.html#automatic).

Nor do you need to "file for" a Creative Commons license. by publishing or distributing a work with an indication that it is subject to a creative commons license, you have released it under that license and anyone may thereafter use it subject to the terms of that license. This is done with a statement such as  "Released under the Creative Commons CC-BY-SA 4.0 license." Such a statement is often placed near the (optional but strongly recommended) copyright notice, but that is not required. if you wish to specify the form of attribution (for example to a specified pseudonym) or a URL to use in providing attribution, that should ideally be placed near the license statement. If the work carries a list of credits, those may be placed nearby as well, but need not be.

Comment: Gotcha.  So if I register something under US copyright (I want that level of official security), the I can just put the CC symbol on it and it will be licensed as creative commons?

Comment: @CMB You need more than a symbol, you need an explicit statement that the work is released or placed under the CC license, and which CC license. Ideally which version. A single sentence such as "Released under the Creative Commons CC-BY-SA 4.0 license." will do.

Comment: Good point.  You're right.  Still, once I register copyright, I can include the appropriate statement to grant creative commons permissions and then distribute it?

Comment: @CMB You are fully protected for all purposes under US law if you register within three months of initial publication, meaning up to three months **after** publication. Even if later than that, if you register before anyone infringes, you have met the threshold for statutory damages in an infringement suit. So you can include the statement (and a copyright notice), distribute the work, and then file for registration if you wish. Just don't wait too long.

Comment: Seigel That's for copyright, yes?  As far as I understand, there is no record maintained for creative commons.  So publish with a copyright notice and a creative commons declaration, then apply for copyright within three months?  Simple enough.

Comment: @CMB Yes, that is exactly correct. I think there **are** people who compile voluntary lists of works under CC licenses, but far from all CC users list themselves, and listing has no legal effect. Oh strictly speaking "register a copyright" not 'apply for" one. But just follow the link above.